# Google Sheets: Filter Row if it does not contains HYPERLINK

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet which has a column where most cells contain a hyperlink, I am looking for a way to find cells which do not contain a hyperlink and delete those rows.

Filter by condition -> Text Contains -> `=HYPERLINK` does not work as it searches for the visible text and not the formula.

Comment: If the cell is purely a hyperlink and nothing more, you can use the `ISURL` formula to check whether it's a formula. Unfortunately, it won't work if the hyperlink has a link label or otherwise doesn't look like an URL. Not sure if there's a way to determine whether a cell contains a hyperlink using formulae.